# Yii2 данные из связной таблицы

Tags: yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в конечной модели(item) получить данные из связной модели(pesrItem.cnt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день.

Для этого в моделях надо прописать связи.

В модели Item

```
public function getPersItem()
{
   return $this->hasOne(PersItem::class, ['item_id' => 'id'])
}
```

Тогда в модели Item Вы сможете получить данные таким образом.

```
echo $model->persItem->id; // получаете id одной записи из таблицы PresItem
```

Если надо получить несколько id, то связь будет через hasMany() и выводить данные в цикле.

Подробней [здесь](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-active-record.md#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-).

Видео [урок](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/89/related-models-on-yii2) по работе со связными моделями, всего пять часов, но оно того стоит.

Comment: а если юзая with(items мне получить данные)

Comment: Читайте по ссылке, там всё расписано. Можно и так, а можно ещё добавить и joinWith(). Всё зависит от того, что Вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Если у Вас есть связь getItems(), то тогда можно использовать with('items'). Если нет, то Вы ничего не получите.

Comment: Добавил ещё одну полезную ссылку.